# Jquery deferred execution

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to learn jQuery `Deferred`s and best way to learn is probably is to try understand them on your own examples. I'm trying to `show` then `fadeout` (1000 ms) a message to the user after he clicked button and after ajax succesfully executed. When the user clicks several in  second, message is displayed only once. I would like this scenario:
user clicks 7 times in one second, and that message box shows and fades out seven times in a row. The whole proccess would probably took 7 second.
Few lines of code:

```
    $("#AddToCart").click(function () {

            var wantedquantity = $("#wantedquantity").val();              
      $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ROOT + "Cart/AddToCart",
                data: { idd: '@Model.Id', quantity: wantedquantity },
                success: function () {             
                    $("#cartNumber").load(ROOT + 'Cart/_NOfItemsInCart');
                    $("#MessageAddedToCart").css("visibility", "visible").css("display", "block").css("box-shadow", "6px 6px 4px 4px #808080").html("Product added to cart");
                    $("#MessageAddedToCart").fadeOut(1000, function (){
                    });
               }
          });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Also, you say clicking 7 times the message box should show and fade out 7 times, but do you want to actually POST 7 times in a row too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [`.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue-queueName-callback-next-) would work here:

```
$("#AddToCart").click(function() {
    $(this).queue(function(next) {
        $.ajax({
            // other stuff
            success: function() {
                $("#cartNumber").load(ROOT + 'Cart/_NOfItemsInCart');
                $("#MessageAddedToCart")
                    .css({
                         visibility: "visible",
                         display: "block",
                         "box-shadow": "6px 6px 4px 4px #808080"
                    })
                    .html("Product added to cart");
                    .fadeOut(1000, function() {
                        next()
                    });
            },
            error: function() { next(); }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It works(displays messages as expected) if you ignore the fact that ajax doesn't work. Can .queue work with ajax as ajax returns  asynchronously?

Comment: Yes, it can. Did you replace `// other stuff`?

Comment: Yes. I did. There were few mistakes. It works just as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can chain handlers for a `deferred` together using [.then](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/). See the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var requests = [];
$("#AddToCart").click(function () {
    var new_def = $.Deferred();
    var call = function() {
        $.ajax({
            // other stuff
            success: function() {
                // other stuff
                $("#MessageAddedToCart").fadeOut(1000, function() {
                    // remove request from requests
                    var idx = requests.indexOf(new_def);
                    if (idx !== -1) {
                        requests.splice(idx, 1);
                    }
                    // mark it as resolved
                    new_def.resolve();
                });
            }
        });
    };

    var def = requests[requests.length-1];
    if (def) {
        def.done(call);
    } else {
        call();
    }
    requests.push(new_def);
});
```